# [Scala][Spark] Nullpointer exception on .toDF in Scala Spark in sparkJob

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I need to get a bunch of JSON data messages from a Kafka Stream and aggregate them into a single file before putting them on S3.
I managed to get the bunch of JSON files as well as to make them into a list.
However, when I try to convert my list of case classes into a DataFrame, I get a nullptr exception at **org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.localSeqToDatasetHolder**.

Would you please be so kind as to tell me what is causing it and how to fix it ? I've been on this bug for hours.

```
final case class Coords(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)

final case class Person(
    name: String,
    peacescore: Double,
)

final case class SaveableEvent(
    peacewatcherID : Int,
    timestamp: String,
    location: Coords,
    words: List[String],
    persons: List[Person]
)
```

```
package saveaggregate

import play.api.libs.json._

import java.io.FileNotFoundException
import java.io.IOException
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter 

import scala.io.Source

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig

import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame, SaveMode, Row, SQLContext}

import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object Main extends App {
  def experiment() = {
    val filePath = ""

    val accessKey = ""
    val secretKey = ""
    
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
        .setMaster("local[*]")
        .setAppName("save_aggregate")
        .set("spark.driver.host", "127.0.0.1")

    val streamContext = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(15))
    val sparkContext = streamContext.sparkContext
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._


    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", accessKey)
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secretKey)
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")

    val kafkaParams = Map(
        "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
        "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
        "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
        "group.id" -> "alert"
    )
    
    val topics = Array("foo")

    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
        streamContext,
        PreferConsistent,
        Subscribe[String,String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )

    stream.flatMap(record => {
        // Declare classes format to deserialize
        implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]
        implicit val coordsFormat = Json.format[Coords]
        implicit val eventFormat = Json.format[Event]
        val json = Json.parse(record.value())
        eventFormat.reads(json).asOpt
      })
      .map(event => {
        println(event)
        val serializedTime = event.timestamp.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
        SaveableEvent(event.peacewatcherID, serializedTime, event.location, event.words, event.persons)
      })
      .map(event => List.fill(1)(event))
      .reduce((a, b) => a ++ b)
      .map(event => {println(event); event})
      .map(
        eventRows => {
          val eventList = eventRows.toList
          val df = eventList.toDF // nullptr exception here
          val path = "s3a://path"
          putOnS3(df, path)
          eventList
        }
      )
      .print()

    streamContext.start()
    streamContext.awaitTermination()
  }

  def getFromS3(configuredSpark: SparkSession, inAddress: String) = {
    configuredSpark.read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .json(inAddress)
  }

  def putOnS3(df: DataFrame, outAddress: String) = {
    println(outAddress)
    df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(outAddress)
  }
  
  experiment()
}
```

[console logs of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSEpv.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
// try or give example JSON
 
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, OFormat}
import scala.util.Try

final case class Coords(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
object Coords {
  implicit val CoordsFormatter: OFormat[Coords] = Json.format[Coords]
  def apply(str: String): Option[Coords] = {
    Try(Json.parse(str).asOpt[Coords]).getOrElse(None)
  }
}

final case class Person(
                         name: String,
                         peacescore: Double,
                       )
object Person {
  implicit val PersonFormatter: OFormat[Person] = Json.format[Person]
  def apply(str: String): Option[Person] = {
    Try(Json.parse(str).asOpt[Person]).getOrElse(None)
  }
}

final case class SaveableEvent(
                                peacewatcherID : Int,
                                timestamp: String,
                                location: Coords,
                                words: List[String],
                                persons: List[Person]
                              )
object SaveableEvent {
  implicit val SaveableEventFormatter: OFormat[SaveableEvent] = Json.format[SaveableEvent]

  def apply(str: String): Option[SaveableEvent] = {
    Try(Json.parse(str).asOpt[SaveableEvent]).getOrElse(None)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it solves the issue ;)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your input @mvasyliv . I tried your changes and they didn't fix it.

Comment: please, example your JSON